# Javascript 'associative' array madness

Tags: javascript, arrays

It seems impossible to me to realize this array structure

```
[{ "Field1" : "Foo"}, {"Field2" : "Bar" }]
```

with following code

```
    var matching = new Array();

    $('tr[type="entity"]').each(function(){

        var $select = $(this).find('select');

        matching[$select.attr('id')] = $select.val();               
    });
```

This

```
alert(JSON.stringify(matching))
```

returns [ ] always. If it would be php my array would look like that

```
$matching = array(
    "Field1" => "Foo",
    "Field2" => "Bar"
);
```

I know there is no associative array in javascript. However how can I realize such an array based on my code.

Comment: Your php example does not match the js example on the first line. Which one are you looking for?

Comment: Oh I'm a bit confused now. The structure in your first example is different than what you would get with the PHP version. What do you actually want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects are associative arrays. Consider using `var matching = new Object();` instead, and check to make sure the function is actually running (i.e. that the `tr` you expect actually exist).

Comment: Or just `var matching = {};` (but of course, that's not OO if that's what you're going for).

Comment: You know this will return `{id: value, id: value}` and not `[{id: value}, {id: value}]` as in OP's desired structured. Depending on OP's needs, this might be more suitable than his desired structured, but it is worth noting that you're returning a different structure from the intended.